# Dual monitors not working on ASUS laptop via DisplayLink USB 3.0 Adapter

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, asus

Hello guys and girls this is my first question on your forum. I have Ubuntu 16.04.04 LTS fully installed on a ASUS F555L laptop and I am trying to run two ASUS Designo MX259H monitors in addition to my laptop display. I ordered a Diamond Multimedia BVU3500 USB 3.0 to HDMI/DVI Multi-Display Adapter and installed the DisplayLink Linux driver from http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu to no avail.

I cannot even get my USB 3.0 ports on my laptop to see the Diamond adapter but it can see every other device i plug into it such as flash drives, etc. Any help would be greatly appreiciated as I put a good amount of money down on another monitor and this adapter. Pretty annoying not to be able to make it work but I have faith someone here has the solution.

ASUS F555L Specifications

ASUS Laptop F555LA-NS72 Intel Core i7 5500U (2.40 GHz) 12 GB DDR3L Memory 1 TB HDD Intel HD Graphics 5500 15.6"

Comment: I should have noted I have one of the two ASUS Designo MX259H monitors running fine via my HDMI port on the laptop. Getting the second ASUS Designo MX259H monitor to run via the Diamond USB 3.0 adapter is the issue now. Nothing but a black screen on that monitor.